# My EA loses money when I breakeven

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, forex

I have a very successful EA which is designed to move my stop loss to breakeven when I get 50 pips "in the money". So pretty basic stuff, however, I still lose a small amount of money on the trade that hit the new breakeven price - of course the breakeven price being equal to the `OrderOpenPrice`.

Granted, I don't lose as much as I would if my price were to hit the original S/L but my net profit on trading position that hit the breakeven price was NIL. I've made no modifications to the EA code.

I'm thinking my broker maybe moved the `stopLevel` figures so my breakeven price can no longer reach the `OrderOpenPrice` but I can't be sure.

Does anyone have this issue and how would I go about solving this?

Here is the code. **The relevant code starts on line 537** ;
https://github.com/indomtrading/ea/commit/5de74283f02ebee634952d5d204e21749ea25714

Comment: Hello. Not sure that 800+ lines is minimum in MCVE. Maybe you could show an example from mt4 if your  `OrderStopLoss()` was slightly (several ticks) below `OrderOpenPrice()`- because it is also possible that Osl=Oop and net result is negative because of commission and swap? Usually broker do not have what is your entry price when you move Osl - current price matters and `MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_STOPLEVEL)*Point()`. It is also possible that sometimes it is zero and in other cases small loss because of slippage - if you set slippage to zero then you want have such problem (but practical ones)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your contribution. Slippage is a good point, I did a latency test and I'm getting 0.91ms on the VPS I'm using, which is extremely fast. My slippage in my EA is set to 300ms. I'll try reducing this to zero this but I've also emailed the quant team of my broker.  Thanks

Comment: you can try to find LMAX DOM, or something similar to see that price jumps, no guarantee it is executed at your level even at AAA broker. latency is of no relation to slippage, slippage is how much ticks you allow price to run over, after your move stop loss, your stop loss is at your brokers side not at your VPS. try to find in logs where was stoploss that you requested and where it was executed - that may answer your questions, if not - compare expected with order open price

Answer (score 1):

### To reach a B/E-state, there are two distinct processes to watch:

- one is the PriceDOMAIN distance between the XTO **`OrderOpenPrice()`** and the "new" value one wishes to set a "future" XTO **`OrderStopLoss()`**.
- the other is the Broker-side accrued sum of all Commissions + Fees + Swaps

While 
**`OrderCommission()`** + **`OrderSwap()`** could be inspected explicitly ( as have been accrued and have been a part of "**a-just-theoretical**" **`OrderProfit()`** ), any additional costs, associated by your Broker's "Terms & Conditions" with an XTO on **`OrderClose()`** or on any of materialised `{ OrderStopLoss() | OrderTakeProfit() }` does not show up, until the XTO operation is finished and such costs get visible **after** such position was terminated.

If the EA does not precisely account for both of these principal P/L-drivers in evaluating BreakEven,
it may systematically move your money into losses.

Check both of these in the EA B/E-driving policies against your Broker "Terms & Conditions" so as to avoid the so far observed losses.

---

### Nota Bene:

while the slippage may appear during a live-trading session, the nature of the slippage-mechanics ought be ( sure, outside of the Fundamental major events ) principally symmetric .. sometimes gaining, sometimes loosing a pip or a few. In case your Broker does not exhibit a symmetrical nature, some investigation is in place, but that does not explain a systematically loosing EA-trade automation.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, when you move your `OrderStopLoss()` to `OrderOpenPrice()` it may close with slippage so loss instead of breakeven. In order to fight with that, `OrderModify()` your `OrderStopLoss()`to `OrderOpenPrice()+2*Point`, if there's a small slippage you will have a tick gain or zero

Answer (score 0):

You need to factor in Swap and Commission.